# How to find the error in my matrix multiplication calculator

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, nested

```
package practise;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Dimensions Of Matrix A : ");
        int rowsa = sc.nextInt();
        int colsa = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Dimensions Of Matrix B : ");
        int rowsb = sc.nextInt();
        int colsb = sc.nextInt();
        int a[][] = new int[rowsa][colsa];
        int b[][] = new int[rowsb][colsb];
        int c[][] = new int[rowsa][colsb];
        
        
        for(int i = 0;i<rowsa;i++) {
            
            for(int j = 0;j<colsa;j++) {
                
                a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                
            }   
            }
            for(int i = 0;i<rowsb;i++) {
                
                for(int j = 0;j<colsb;j++) {
                    
                    b[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                            
                }           
            
            }
            
            
            if(colsa == rowsb){
                
                for(int j = 0;j<colsb;j++) {
                    
                    for(int i =0;i<rowsa;i++) {
                        
                        c[rowsa][colsb] = a[j][i] * b[i][j] ;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            else{System.out.println("Matrix Multiplication Not Possible");}
            
            
            System.out.println("The Result is:"+ c[rowsa][colsb]);
            
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
```

I am trying to make a matrix multiplication calculator using the Row * Column formula of maths. It is throwing this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at practise/practise.Practise.main(Practise.java:45)
```

Comment: is line 45 `c[rowsa][colsb] = a[j][i] * b[i][j]`? That one looks like an immediate red flag

Answer (score 0):

```
int c[][] = new int[rowsa][colsb];
[...]
c[rowsa][colsb] = a[j][i] * b[i][j] ;
```

This is your problem. `c` has columns ranging from index `0` to `rowsa - 1` (making it `rowsa` columns). Then you try to write to position `rowsa` which is clearly outside of the array. (the same goes for colsb btw).

Quick example:

```
rowsa = 3;
colsb = 3;

int c[][] = new int[rowsa][colsb]
```

Now `c` looks like:

```
    row\col  0 1 2
          0  0 0 0
          1  0 0 0
          2  0 0 0
```

So which Element are you trying to get with `c[rowsa][colsb]` also known as `c[3][3]`? This one (marked as `X`):

```
row\col  0 1 2
      0  0 0 0
      1  0 0 0
      2  0 0 0
               X
```

Except that's not even inside your array (hence: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Comment: can you please give a fix?

Comment: it's... not that simple ;) Looking through your code, you definitely misunderstand how matrix multiplication works and/or how arrays work. For example: What are you trying to print at the end as your result? c[whatever][whatever] will always be a single value. The result of a matrix multiplication is another matrix though. It's easy enough to avoid the exception (just change the indexes to some that actually exist), but while you won't get that exception anymore, your result will still simply be wrong.